# How to get the name of the process which is streaming media over mediaserver process in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I couldn't find detailed information on the Internet.

But as far as I know, `mediaserver` process which is located in `/system/bin/mediaserver` controls the media transactions in Android.

For example while streaming video on `youtube` application, this media server seems to be opening port to the remote server and downloading the content as it seems in

```
cat /proc/net/tcp
```

The linux UID of mediaserver app is 1013, which is an internal Android UID.

For a new socket connection, I'm getting the application UID by checking the open ports

But for this mediaserver process case, I get the UID 1013 as mediaserver has opened the port.

The problem is when I call `getRunningAppProcesses`, this mediaserver app is not listed in the list.

To be more specific, `getRunningAppProcesses()` returns only the package names in the output of `ps` command, not showing e.g. `/system/bin/mediaserver` or `/system/bin/keystore` etc.

So I'd need to know which application's caused mediaserver to open a new port to the remote service. How to obtain the original application name or pid in this case? I couldn't figure out if this could actually be done or a restriction of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You could know if you track the intent created to launch the service. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to get that information without tracking system calls (i.e., modifying the firmware to trace it)